# Getting string from another class and transfering it to url

Tags: java, string, class, public

I need to get string from another class like:
String called url is determined in Class 2 below, i need to get it and to copyUrlToFile(url, result + ""\plugins\TentMod") folder, where url is string i need to get from another class, and result is folder path from folder choser.

Class 1

```
package me.ArsenArsen.TentName.installer;

import java.io.File;

public class TMInstaller {

    protected Shell shlTentmodInstaller;
    private Text txtInstallerHasStarted;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TMInstaller window = new TMInstaller();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shlTentmodInstaller.open();
        shlTentmodInstaller.layout();
        while (!shlTentmodInstaller.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shlTentmodInstaller = new Shell();
        shlTentmodInstaller.setImage(null);
        shlTentmodInstaller.setTouchEnabled(true);
        shlTentmodInstaller.setSize(450, 228);
        shlTentmodInstaller.setText("TentMod Installer");

        Button btnNewButton = new Button(shlTentmodInstaller, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
                DirectoryDialog dialog = new DirectoryDialog(shlTentmodInstaller, SWT.OPEN);
                dialog.setFilterPath("c:\\");
                dialog.setText("Select your server folder");
                String result = dialog.open();
                boolean success = (new File(result + "//" + "TentMod")).mkdirs();
                String textboxtxt = txtInstallerHasStarted.getText();
                if (!success) {
                    txtInstallerHasStarted.setText(textboxtxt + "\r\nMaking folder FAILED! Did folder exist???");
                } else {
                    txtInstallerHasStarted.setText(textboxtxt + "\r\nMaking folder SUCESS\r\nDownloading files!");
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(Adv_Settings.class.urls);
                        File destination = new File(result + "plugins\\TentMod\\tent.schematic");
                        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, destination);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                        e1.printStackTrace(pw);
                        String err = sw.toString();
                        txtInstallerHasStarted.setText(txtInstallerHasStarted.getText() + "\r\nINTERNAL ERROR\r\nWIEW STACK TRACE:\r\n" + err);
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 10, 414, 33);
        btnNewButton.setText("Install TentMod");
        String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        txtInstallerHasStarted = new Text(shlTentmodInstaller, SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.MULTI);
        txtInstallerHasStarted.setText("Current Working Directory is: " + currentDir + "\r\nInstaller has started...\r\nWaiting for command...");
        txtInstallerHasStarted.setBounds(10, 49, 414, 104);

        Button btnNewButton_1 = new Button(shlTentmodInstaller, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
                Adv_Settings config = new Adv_Settings();
                config.open();

            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(10, 159, 127, 25);
        btnNewButton_1.setText("Settings (ADVANCED)");

        Button btnExit = new Button(shlTentmodInstaller, SWT.NONE);
        btnExit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
                shlTentmodInstaller.close();
            }
        });
        btnExit.setBounds(349, 159, 75, 25);
        btnExit.setText("Exit");

    }
}
```

And i need public string urls from second class:

```
package me.ArsenArsen.TentName.installer;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;

public class Adv_Settings {
    private Text text;
    public String urls = new String("http://arsenovic.host56.com/tent.schematic");
    public String jar_url = new String("http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/tentmod/files/");
    private Text text_1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Adv_Settings window = new Adv_Settings();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell = new Shell();
        shell.setSize(276, 134);
        shell.setText("Advanced Settings - TentMod Installer");


        Button btnApply = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnApply.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
                if(text.getText().equals("")){
                    urls = "http://arsenovic.host56.com/tent.schematic";
                } else urls = text.getText();
                if(text_1.getText().equals("")){
                    jar_url = "http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/tentmod/files/";
                } else jar_url = text.getText();
            }
        });
        btnApply.setBounds(91, 64, 75, 25);
        btnApply.setText("Apply");

        Button btnOk = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnOk.setBounds(10, 64, 75, 25);
        btnOk.setText("Ok");

        Button btnCancel = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnCancel.setBounds(172, 64, 75, 25);
        btnCancel.setText("Cancel");

        text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setBounds(10, 10, 237, 21);
        text.setMessage("Insert your specific URL");

        text_1 = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        text_1.setBounds(10, 37, 237, 21);
        text_1.setMessage("Insert your specific URL for JAR file");

        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

String is made public, and this is swt-mainly development with bit of apache to download files.

Comment: There isn't even a question mark.

Comment: @Smutje that dont mean its not question

Comment: You want to conver the string named urls to the URL class object?

Comment: Yes @Jayaprasad and string is in another class

Comment: Why can't you use the constructor of URL class? URL(string).. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Comment: @Jayaprasad i have problem witch is string is in ANOTHER class

Comment: @Jayaprasad is it going to work if i extend class??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the urls string to static variable and access the variable as className.variableName.

```
public class Adv_Settings {
        private Text text;
        public static String urls = new String("http://arsenovic.host56.com/tent.schematic");
        public String jar_url = new String("http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/tentmod/files/");
        private Text text_1;
         ...
    }
public class TMInstaller {

    protected Shell shlTentmodInstaller;
    private Text txtInstallerHasStarted;

protected void createContents() {
        .....
        URL url = new URL(Adv_Settings.urls);

}
```

Comment: Is it gonna be editable thrue textbox?

Comment: I am not sure what your codes does and how your code works. As the variable is static it is subject to change. Unless a variable is marked as final it can be changed. To be specific to your comment, yes it is editable through text box.

Comment: So @Jayaprasad U got marked as working :D